# oauth2 website on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, go

I am using https://code.google.com/p/goauth2/source/browse/oauth/example/oauthreq.go to try to access an admin only (via app.yaml) url on my site:

```
go run main.go -code CODE
```

runs against the Google api default url and returns my info:

```
{
  ...
  "gender": "male",
  "locale": "en-GB"
}
```

So I've got the right code at least!

But accessing my website (specifying `-request_url`) returns the HTML for the Google account login page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Google Accounts</title>
```

So there's probably something wrong with my GAE setup... The Google APIs Console has the correct "Home Page URL". Any ideas?

I have tried with my custom domain and my appspot domain, but accessing an admin-only url only redirects my client to the Google account login page.

I see the GET request being sent with header `Authorization: Bearer CODE`.

Comment: oauth is to autherize your app for a user, its not for authorizing some app against some app, if your app should be able to receive request also with an oauth token you have to write this code in your app. so usal flow is, you start your app, no user, make request to oauth url, user will allow request, you receive token for permit, with this token you can now access the user details.

Answer (score 0):

Your application is not an OAuth Consumer.  Google is the provider, but your application needs to request access, you as a user need to approve it, and then your application can consume the Google APIs.  Sending an OAuth token to your application doesn't get you a session cookie.